# Creating stored procedure in Oracle -17110 - Warning: execution completed with warning

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, execute

I tried creating following stored procedure found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) using Execute Query client connected to my Oracle server (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_emp (employee_id NUMBER) AS
   tot_emps NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM employees
      WHERE employees.employee_id = remove_emp.employee_id;
   tot_emps := tot_emps - 1;
   END;
/
```

I'm getting following,

> Procedure created.
>
> 17110 - Warning: execution completed with warning

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Always use **SHOW ERRORS** to see the complete compilation error stack.

I don't know what error you are getting, because it works for me:

```
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE remove_emp (employee_id NUMBER) AS
  2     tot_emps NUMBER;
  3     BEGIN
  4        DELETE FROM emp
  5        WHERE emp.empno = remove_emp.employee_id;
  6     tot_emps := tot_emps - 1;
  7     END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err;
No errors.
SQL>
```

To execute:

```
SQL> exec remove_emp(9999);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I took this procedure from Oracle docs. Even after modifying according to your suggestion I'm getting the same warning. Seems I can't try SHOW ERRORS on my client. (Execute Query)

Comment: The example in the documentation is executed in `HR` schema. So, do you have `employees` table? Or do you have the sample schema like `SCOTT` or `HR`?

Comment: found the problem, I need to use "Execute as single statement" feature in EQ :) Seems EQ removes semi colons by default.

Comment: @udarak, ok. I added execute example from sqlplus.